# Ajax validation not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Im working with Codeigniter 1.7.2, and I found this ajax validation, that seems not to work in the version I have. Here's the code:

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
            {               
                echo json_encode($results);
            }
            else
            {
                $data['results'] = $results;
                $this->load->view('myView', $data);
            }
```

I clearly understand that this line doesn't work with my version:

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request()
```

So I'm looking for an alternative, or how can I fix it. I couldn't find any topics related to this issue. I'll appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: You can duplicate the functionality.  The type of request is a parameter in the $_SERVER array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constants.php file add :

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

then in your code instead of

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request()
```

use

```
if (IS_AJAX) {...}
```

Comment: I added the constant but event after that its not working.